# get average value from a tree of nodes

Tags: algorithm, root, average

I have to implement this method:

```
public int GetAverage(Node root){
   //TODO implement
}
```

this method should get average value of all nodes of root tree. where :

```
public interface Node {
   int getValue();

   List<Node> getNodes();
}
```

do you have any ideas how to implement this method?

thank you

my attempt:

```
public static double value;
public static int count;
 public static double getAverage(Node root) {
 count++;
 value += root.getValue();
 for (Node node : root.getNodes()) {
 getAverage(node);
 }
 return value / count;
 }
```

but how to do it without the static fields outside of the method?

Comment: Traverse the tree, accumulating the values in an integer and keep a node count. Divide the accumulated sum by the node count. Have you tried anything?

Comment: recursively :) What have you tried?

Comment: I treid it recursively.. no success. Can you show me the code?

Comment: @JohnSmith No, you show us your attempt first. :)

Comment: Mohammed: I tried the same as you said, but in every way I see it, I had to create some static fields outside the method to keep the values.. Do you see any way how to implement only the method, without creating any fields outside of it ?

Comment: public static double value;
public static int count;
 public static double getAverage(Node root) {
 count++;
 value += root.getValue();
 for (Node node : root.getNodes()) {
 getAverage(node);
 }
 return value / count;
 }

Comment: Methods can have more than one parameter. Methods can also return multiple values using objects or arrays. If you realize this, then it should be trivial to do this without static variables. Carry the value and count information in the arguments to each call of your function and build your solution together using a top-down approach in terms of parent-child.

Comment: @JohnSmith You'd have to pass the count and value to the recursive function.

Answer (score 1):

Simply traverse through all nodes and remember the count and the overall sum of all values. Then calculate the average. This is an example written in Java.

```
public interface INode {
    int getValue();

    List<INode> getNodes();
}

public class Node implements INode {
    private List<INode> children = new ArrayList<INode>();
    private int value;

    @Override
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public List<INode> getNodes() {
        return children;
    }

    public static int getAverage(INode root) {
        if (root == null)
            return 0;

        Counter c = new Counter();
        calculateAverage(root, c);

        return c.sum / c.count;
    }

    class Counter {
        public int sum;
        public int count;
    }

    private static void calculateAverage(INode root, Counter counter) {
        if (root == null)
            return;

        counter.sum += root.getValue();
        counter.count++;

        // recursively through all children
        for (INode child : root.getNodes())
            calculateAverage(child, counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a null check in calculateAverage over get nodes

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double getAverage(Node root) {
    Pair p = new Pair(0,0);
    algo(root, p);
    return ((double) p.element1) / ((double) p.element2);
}

private static void algo(Node root, Pair acc) {
    for(Node child : root.getNodes()) {
        algo(child, acc);
    }
    acc.sum += root.getValue();
    acc.nbNodes++;
}
```

With Pair defined as follows:

```
public class Pair {

    public int sum;
    public int nbNodes;

    public Pair(int elt1, int elt2) {
        this.sum = elt1;
        this.nbNodes = elt2;
    }

}
```